# Full css ticker : making a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ticker

I have this code for full css ticker.

Currently, item 1 appears once the list is fully passed, so the list start again.

I'd like to make a "loop". I mean I'd like to get item 1 just after item 4.

Sorry if I'm not clear...

I'd like to know if there is a way to improve with some jquery ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
.ticker-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #ffc846;
  padding-left: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.ticker-wrap .ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
  animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
.ticker-wrap .ticker__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 3em;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticker-wrap">
<div class="ticker">
  <div class="ticker__item">item 1</div>
  <div class="ticker__item">item 2</div>
  <div class="ticker__item">item 3</div>
  <div class="ticker__item">item 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a seperate animation for each item and schedule item 1 to enter the dom at the appropriate time. Use the animation-delay CSS property to appropriately schedule each item.